# Dataframe Index Operations not working as wanted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My current code

```
M = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=range(6))

for i  in M.index:
    M.loc[i,0:2] = 1550

for i  in M.index:
    M.loc[i,3:6] = 300

#########################################################################
FOa = 0.00123
i = 0
j = 1

while i < 10:
    while j < 3:
        M.iloc[i,j] = (1+2*FOa)*M.iloc[i+1,j] - FOa*(M.iloc[i+1,j-1] + M.iloc[i+1,j+1])
        j = j +1

    i = i + 1
```

The Output comes out to be the following

```
      0     1        2    3    4    5
0  1550  1550  1551.55  300  300  300
1  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
2  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
3  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
4  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
5  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
6  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
7  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
8  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
9  1550  1550     1550  300  300  300
```

My question is why is only the first row of Column 2 being modified and not all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because value to `j` is only assigned outside of the two loops, hence after the first iteration of the inner loop `j` is 3 and it doesn't enter the loops for the subsiquent rows.

The problem can be fixed like this:

```
while i < 10:
    j = 1
    while j < 3:
        M.iloc[i,j] = (1+2*FOa)*M.iloc[i+1,j] - FOa*(M.iloc[i+1,j-1] + M.iloc[i+1,j+1])
        j = j +1

    i = i + 1
```

But since you refer to the row bellow in `M.iloc[i+i,j]` you would probably want to iterate until the row before last and specify the value of the last row after the loop.